# grub2-mkconfig not finding any operating system

Tags: linux, fedora, grub2, dual-boot, boot-loader

I'm trying to re-generate the grub2 config files so that entries for all operating systems in this machine are added to Grub2 menu. This is a UEFI system with Fedora 32 as main OS and FreeBSD as a secondary (the one I'm trying to add as a boot option).

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg
```

Normally, when I do this I see a list of all my kernel images and any other OS installed in the system. When I run this now only *"Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration"*.

This is my partition table:

```
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Numero  Inicio  Fin    Tamaño  Sistema de ficheros  Nombre                Banderas
 2      316MB   419MB  104MB   fat16                EFI System Partition  arranque, esp
 1      419MB   420MB  524kB
 3      420MB   112GB  111GB                        FreeBSD
 5      112GB   166GB  53,7GB  ext4
 6      166GB   500GB  335GB                                              lvm
```

My fat16 EFI partition is still there, mounted at `/boot/efi/EFI` and containing two directories (with files):

```
[root@localhost boot]# ls /boot/efi/EFI/
BOOT  fedora
```

And my /boot directory still has all the initram and kernel image files:

```
[root@localhost boot]# ls
config-5.1.0-1.vanilla.knurd.1.fc29.x86_64                initramfs-5.1.0-1.vanilla.knurd.1.fc30.x86_64-old.img
config-5.1.0-1.vanilla.knurd.1.fc30.x86_64                initramfs-5.5.1-250.vanilla.knurd.1.fc30.x86_64.img
config-5.5.1-250.vanilla.knurd.1.fc30.x86_64              loader
efi                                                       memtest86+-5.01
elf-memtest86+-5.01                                       System.map-5.1.0-1.vanilla.knurd.1.fc29.x86_64
extlinux                                                  System.map-5.1.0-1.vanilla.knurd.1.fc30.x86_64
grub2                                                     System.map-5.5.1-250.vanilla.knurd.1.fc30.x86_64
initramfs-0-rescue-0dde65918cd54be6bb957c7cc7a472bb.img   vmlinuz-0-rescue-0dde65918cd54be6bb957c7cc7a472bb
initramfs-5.1.0-1.vanilla.knurd.1.fc29.x86_64.img         vmlinuz-5.1.0-1.vanilla.knurd.1.fc29.x86_64
initramfs-5.1.0-1.vanilla.knurd.1.fc30.x86_64.img         vmlinuz-5.1.0-1.vanilla.knurd.1.fc30.x86_64
initramfs-5.1.0-1.vanilla.knurd.1.fc30.x86_64-nvidia.img  vmlinuz-5.5.1-250.vanilla.knurd.1.fc30.x86_64
```

After updating grub2 files and restarting my computer is booting directly into Fedora, the grub2 screen has disapeared.

I have been reading about grub2 and searching all around, there are many possible solutions but mostly for MBR/BIOS...

What could the problem be?

Comment: Did you install in UEFI boot mode? UEFI and BIOS are not compatible, once you start booting in one mode you cannot switch. Or grub can only boot other installs in same boot mode, or UEFI in your case.

Comment: Hi. Yes, installed in UEFI mode.

Comment: Those files don’t look like Fedora kernel names, and there aren’t any vmlinuz files at all. What is it?

Comment: Do you not have an `/EFI/FREEBSD/BOOTX64.EFI` Folder in the ESP? That should be where the UEFI boot files would be. You may want to back up ESP, to make sure it totally is not overwritten by the FreeBSD installer.

Comment: @oldfred hi, no, I don't seem to have that file. I only have: /boot/efi/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI and /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/BOOTX64.CSV

Comment: @jsbillings yes there are many vmlinuz files, those are the Fedora kernels, for example:
vmlinuz-5.5.1-250.vanilla.knurd.1.fc30.x86_64. May check the horizontal scroller?
Those files are in /boot.